# Commission Junction links are registering tons of (probably false) clicks

Tags: web-crawlers, advertising, spam, affiliate

I have a sidebar of commission junction ads, and they are plain text links (a-tags) with rel="nofollow" attributes in them

I'm getting hundreds of "clicks" per day in my daily stats on CJ's dashboard.

This seems likely to be wrong, because I have Adsense ads as well, and I usually get < 5 clicks per day from that.

Is it possible that webcrawlers are clicking my no-follow ads? how do I go about diagnosing and stopping these false clicks?

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that automated robots are crawling your `nofollow` links.   Only a few robots such as Googlebot pay attention to those tags.   Other robots ignore them.

You can use one of these techniques to block them better:

- Send them through a redirector that is blocked by *robots.txt*.   More robots obey that than `nofollow`.
- Use JavaScript to write the links into the page.   Very few robots execute JavaScript.